# Seeing ClosedChannelException after upgrade to Netty 3.2.7

Tags: netty

I have a server that acts as a pass-through gateway between a large number of clients and an application server. The gateway uses netty and as far as its behavior is concerned, it simply passes any data received from either end to the other (i.e. from a client to the server and vice versa). The established link (made of two netty channels) between a client and the server is closed if either the client or the server closes its end of the connection...
We have been using netty 3.2.4 and have recently upgraded to netty 3.2.7. Since the upgrade we started seeing java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException while running some volume tests. We did not see any issues with the same kind of tests while we were on 3.2.4.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this? I have come across the note from tbocek : [see the last post in this link](https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/2a9c5efe8fc7eb3a18a2891dc4505a8cdf6f54c5) that mentions similar issues. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This was a regression that got fixed in 3.3.0.Final. So consider upgrading to 3.3.1.Final. If you use maven Ou need to change the groupId from org.jboss.netty to io.netty

Comment: Thanks for your reply Norman. I see that [fix](https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/02be2523e0da44f5e0432146419056ec9609b6da) for this regression included removal of close() which was added to address [this ticket](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/74). Is the infinite loop still a possibility?

Comment: @NormanMaurer I am still facing problem with 3.3.1. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560567/channelclosedexception-observered-with-netty-3-2-7-and-3-3-1-under-load