# ClosedChannelException observered with netty 3.2.7 and 3.3.1 under load

Tags: java, ssl, netty, nio

Every thing is working fine when my netty server is not loaded. 
But under load it starts to fail. 
Currently I am using all default settings ( have not set any options ). Please suggest if I need to set any options for handling 2k+ concurrent connections (may close and open very frequently during load)

Here is stack trace with netty 3.2.7. I upgraded to netty 3.3.1  , but it still fails.

> 2012-09-19 16:17:54,864 New I/O server worker #1-11 DEBUG
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler 42 Swallowing an exception
>   raised while writing non-app data
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(NioWorker.java:645)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.writeFromUserCode(NioWorker.java:372)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:137)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:76)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:632)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:593)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:831)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:915)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:849)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:915)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:620)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:282)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:216)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:351)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:282)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:202)
>   ~[netty-3.2.7.Final.jar:na] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.6.0_26] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.6.0_26] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_26]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this problem may be caused by a bug in netty.  I have created a reproducible test case [here](https://github.com/Datomic/datomic-java-examples/wiki/Hornet-SSL-Oddity), and the bug is now fixed on the [3 branch](https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/e784a773f7dbfc4bba49e4ce88ddde82ec3c4e52) of netty.

Answer (score 0):

`ClosedChannelException` means you have continued to use a channel that you have closed yourself. Note that it does not refer to the state of the connection as affected by the peer: i.e. it does not imply that the peer has closed the connection. You have closed this channel.

Comment: why is it coming in only load condition ? I close connections only on shutdown. else connection are closed by clients. Do I need to do any optimization's ?

Comment: @Yok I don't know why you are closing the channel and then continuing to use it. Only you know that. Possibly you have come across a Netty bug.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, I am not closing channel from server side. Probably may be Netty Bug or some optimization required to handle channels in load condition. And I am looking out for these optimization :(.